# Почему выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: lisp

Напишите выражение, выдающее t если в первом заданном списке элемент с указанным номером является числом, во втором списке элемент с соответствующим номером является атомом, а в третьем списке элемент с указанным номером является списком.

```
(let ((L1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
     (L2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ())) 
     (L3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ())))
  (and
   (numberp (cadddr (cddddr L1)))
   (atom (car (cddddr (cddddr L2)))) 
   (listp (cadr (cddddr (cddddr L3))))))
```

Ошибка:
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "numberp" [(anon)]

Comment: А отдельно `(numberp (cadddr (cddddr L1)))` (а также `(cadddr (cddddr L1))`) что печатают? И кстати, какой у вас Lisp?

Comment: пользуюсь сайтом repl.it

Comment: Не знаю, я попробовал там ваш пример ` (let ((L1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
     (L2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ()))
     (L3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ())))
  (and
   (numberp (cadddr (cddddr L1)))
   (atom (car (cddddr (cddddr L2))))
   (listp (cadr (cddddr (cddddr L3))))))`, результат `t`